# Having trouble passing a dictionary from jQuery to Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SubmitUserPicks(Dictionary<string,string> data)
    {

    }
```

Jquery:

```
  var listOfPicks = [{gameID : "2", teamID : "3"}];
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                traditional:true,
                url: "SubmitUserPicks",
                content: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: listOfPicks,
                success: function (result) {
                }
            });
```

But for some reason what is being passed is a dictionary with the key/value of Action and Controller:

[image: From Visual Studio]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass the Dictionary data to Controller string method using jquery post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329765/pass-the-dictionary-data-to-controller-string-method-using-jquery-post)

Answer (score 1):

For a Dictionary you need to have both Key and Value properties, e.g.:

```
data['myDictionary[0].Key'] = "gameID";
data['myDictionary[0].Value'] = 2;

data['myDictionary[1].Key'] = "teamID ";
data['myDictionary[1].Value'] = 3;
```

Then you can send `data` to the server:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional:true,
        url: "SubmitUserPicks",
        content: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
        }
});
```

Hope it helps