# Retrieve a select element options list that has been re-ordered with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, html-select

I have a Dictionary of names/numbers that are passed through to my View from my Controller. This becomes:

```
Model.arrayPositions[x]
```

These are then added to a select list:

```
                <form>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <select id="ListIn" class="select-width" name="SelectionIn" multiple="multiple" size="@Model.arrayPositions.Count">
                            @foreach (var item in Model.arrayPositions)
                            {
                                if (item.Value != null)
                                {
                                    <option class="active" value="@item.Value">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @item.Key)</option>
                                }
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Array items with no value are ignored, the rest is added to the list.

Items can then be added/removed or moved up/down the list using JavaScript:

```
function AddSelected() {
    $('#ListOut option:selected').each(function (i, selected) {
        $('#ListIn').append('<option class="active" value="1">' + selected.innerText + '</option>');
        selected.remove();
    });
}
function RemoveSelected() {
    $('#ListIn option:selected').each(function (i, selected) {
        $('#ListOut').append('<option class="inactive" value="-1">' + selected.innerText + '</option>');
        selected.remove();
    });


function MoveUp() {
    var select1 = document.getElementById("ListIn");

    for (var i = 0; i < select1.length; i++) {
        if (select1.options[i].selected && i > 0 && !select1.options[i - 1].selected)
        {
            var text = select1.options[i].innerText;
            select1.options[i].innerText = select1.options[i - 1].innerText;
            select1.options[i - 1].innerText = text;
            select1.options[i - 1].selected = true;
            select1.options[i].selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

(Moving down is pretty much just the opposite of Moving up)

(#ListOut is simply a second list that has the array items with a value of null added to it)

(The final value is not too important right now, so I'm not specifically retaining it. The order of the list is more important)

I'm changing the order using Javascript to avoid having the page refresh constantly for such a simple action.

However, once I press an update button I'll have a call to my Controller (ASP.NET Core in C#). What I am wondering is how I could retrieve the final values of the list in the new order.

i.e.

If Model.arrayPositions = {a=1,b=2,c=null,d=3}, it would add them to the list as: [a,b,d]

I then use javascript to remove 'a' and move 'd' up, resulting in [d,b]

When I press the update button I would like the retrieve the current list of [d,b] from the View.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Or, alternatively, what other methods might be used to achieve the same goal (note that I wouldn't want page refreshes or partial refreshes if possible).

Comment: why you want to retrieve list again after update. Once list is posted to back-end and updated in store (db?) both front-end and back-end are in sync ?. Otherwise i would suggest to add extra method to controller i.e GetCurrentPositions which will return actual list state and use ajax call on front-end side to call that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax method to hit your controller on the click of your update button

syntax of jquery ajax is:-

```
<script>

$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url : 'controllerNAME/ActionNAME',
        datatype: 'json',
        data : {'parameterOne': parameterone, 'parameterTwo' : parametertwo,...},
        success : function(response)
        {
             alert(response.d)
             //put your logic here for further advancements
        }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I ended up using your suggestion of Ajax and managed to get it sent as a dictionary too using an answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329765/pass-the-dictionary-data-to-controller-string-method-using-jquery-post